# displaying choice in django admin

Tags: python, django, backend

im making a reservation app, i want one of the ways to see the data being in the admin panel but right now i can see everything except for the time, i think it is because its a choice field and in the admin it appears like it wasnt chosen.

**models.py**

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    people = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()


    time_choice = (
        (times_available[0], times_available[0]),
        (times_available[1], times_available[1]),
        (times_available[2], times_available[2]),
        (times_available[3], times_available[3]),
        (times_available[4], times_available[4]),
        (times_available[5], times_available[5]),
        (times_available[6], times_available[6])
    )

    time = models.CharField(
        max_length= 7,
        blank= True,
        null= True,
        choices= time_choice
    )

    phone = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def reservar_mesa(request):
    reserve_form = FormReservarMesa()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        reserve_form = FormReservarMesa(request.POST)

        if reserve_form.is_valid():
            reserve_form.save()
            reserve_form = FormReservarMesa()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")

    context = {'form' : reserve_form}


    return render(request, 'reservas.html', context)
```

my admin.py is the deafault.
i checked and the value is being stored in the database